# Share web page using Javascript/PHP on other websites

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a website thats essentially a people directory.

Each person has a profile page, I want to somehow enabled other webmasters to take a link of code that they can paste on their websites and it will pull information of my page and format it in my brand colours etc, with a link back to my website. Is this possible or is an iframe the only way?

Comment: i did something similar using iframe because many cms won't allow the user to insert script tag & to keep control of the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a iframe but comes with shortcomings, or you can use **jquery/javascript to load the content** from your site inside a div or some container at the remote site. But you would be facing some *cross domain issues* due to the **common origin policy**.

So you have explicitly define in your app to allow headers of origin you prefer, you can do that using **JSONP or CORS**, where jsonp only supports get request, cors is more appropriate way to do and supportallows any type of request.

[CORS](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/), to understand more
[Read this](http://leopard.in.ua/2012/07/08/using-cors-with-rails/)